# Moving object blocks view when walking with gun

Tags: wolfenstein-the-new-order

In Wolfenstein the new order, whenever I am carying a gun instead of a knife or grenade, the view gets blocked by an 'object' moving up and down whilst walking. When standing still, the object is out of view.

The object is like a bar introducing itself from the bottom, where it dissapears as well. It's precence affects gameplay hugely, as (1) it continuously forces ones eyes to refocus and (2) it makes it hard to spot enemies while walking.

In the center of this image, through the crosshair, one can see the bar.

[image: Object blocking view]

I tried going through the in-game video settings, but didn't see anything usefull. I also restarted the game a few times.

Is this a 'feature' or a bug of the game? Is it possible to fix this?

**EDIT:** For completeness, I'm playing the game on a Asus N550JV-CN270H **laptop**:

- Intel Mobile HM86 / Intel Core i7-4700HQ
- GeForce GT750M / Intel HD Graphics 4600 (I seem to have two graphics cards)
- 8GB RAM / DDR3 (SODIMM)
- Windows 8.1
- Samsung 840 EVO 500GB

Answer (score 1):

- Open the console by pressing **CTRL+ALT+Tilde** whilst in the menu screen or whilst playing the game (tilde is the ~ key, usually located below ESC)
- Then a console appears:

[image: Wolfenstein console]

- Enter the the command: cvaradd pm_nobob 1
- Execute it by pressing ENTER.
- Hide the console by pressing CTRL+ALT+Tilde again

Source: http://steamcommunity.com/app/201810/discussions/0/540742579452854491/

Someone also suggested to disable *compression* in the advanced video settings, this did not work for me but did crash the game.

Comment: Crashing the game... that's sort of like a solution, right?

Comment: Thanks! Fixed it for me. I do have to enter it every time I launch the game though?

Comment: @Dimi I'm not too sure, I played this game quite some time ago, and I don't play games often :) But if you do know, please let us know ;)